# Reach shared folder under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, share

I have a local network, before I used windows on all my computers, but now I got an other PC with Ubuntu. How can I reach the shared folders under Ubuntu? In windows it is easy: I just go to `\\computer_name` in the explorer. Is there something like this under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the GUI, just right click on the folder object and select the "Sharing Options" menu choice. It will then guide you through the Samba setup which will allow you to connect to it via Windows UNC naming as pointed out by Dabu.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that Ubuntu by default installs Samba integrated into the environment.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you want the access to work.

You have tools like NFS (Network file system) buildt into Linux. You can define shares, but there is no authentication buildt into the system. Then there's solutions like Samba, which speak the protocol Windows uses for their shares. The setup is alot more complicated, and authorization plays a role. Last but not least there are drivers that can access a Linux Ext partition natively like a Windows drive, but this access method does not work over networks.